# Leaflet Cluster enable and disable not working with jQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am facing problem using leaflet.markercluster.freezable-src plugin with leaflet.markercluster-src in ajax call.

The matter is I have used enableCluster and disableCluster with both ajax and click method. The problem is it is working on click event but not with ajax method.

I am using Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable 0.1.1 and leaflet.markercluster 0.5.0.

One thing also to let you know is the site is using an api which also has clustering code included into it and used for different purposes. Since there is no error showing in console, I am also not sure of whether this also causing the problem I am facing.

To tell you little more both in click event and ajax calling this.eaMarkerClusters.disableClustering which is property of class  L.markerClusterGroup(); which with the help of leaflet.markercluster.freezable-src calling enableCluster and disableCluster methods of that plugin

However, Skeleton of my code setup is given below.

```
function EALocsComponent(lMap) {
  this.eaMarkerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
}

EALocsComponent.prototype.loadData = function (){ 
$.ajax({
    'dataType': "json",
    'url': '/some_service.php',
    data: this.passedArg,
    type: 'get',
    'success': function (data) {
         if(clusterEnabled){
             this.enableClustering();
          }else{
            this.disableClustering (); 
          }
     }
 });
} 

EALocsComponent.prototype.enableClustering = function (){                  
  var self = this;  
    // along with some other code
    self.eaMarkerClusters.enableClustering();                              
}

EALocsComponent.prototype.disableClustering = function (){                  
  var self = this; 
    // along with some other code 
    self.eaMarkerClusters.disableClustering();   

}
```

For your better understanding I have added links of screenshot below of the site as the site is protected. 
1. http://blog.tushersuvro.com/ea-cluster-working-click-event.png
2. http://blog.tushersuvro.com/ea-cluster-not-working-ajax-load.png
3. http://blog.tushersuvro.com/ea-cluster-strange-behavior.png

Please guide me what I can do in this regard. I can use JS plugins but when comes detecting problem in plugin itself I sense I am not quite there to comprehend it.

If you want I can also show you the problem over s k y p e for your better understand.

Comment: Ajax success callback works asynchronously, so print and check what `this` refers to?

Comment: Yes. You mean checking this.eaMarkerClusters after ajax call?

Comment: try `EALocsComponent.prototype.enableClustering()` instead of `this.enableClustering();`

Comment: @AswinKumar actually the code is like this. Thats why I have used this. I have updated the code skeleton part.